# Method signature in REPL

Tags: clojure

I need to use a poorly documented Java library and it would help me if there was a way to see the signature of methods in REPL (for quick experiments).  Consider the following:

```
user=> (import 'x.y.z.C)
user=> (show-method-signature 'C/m)
         C/m String Integer String boolean
```

Is there a tricky method like `show-method-signature` already available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clojure.reflect library is your friend here.

```
(require '[clojure [reflect :as r]])

;; Return the method signature for methods matching a given regex.
;; Params:
;;  cls                - a class (eg. java.util.List) or an instance 
;;  method-name-regex  - a regex string to match against the method name 
(defn method-sig [cls method-name-regex]
  (let [name-regex (re-pattern method-name-regex)]
     (filter #(re-matches name-regex (str (:name %)))
             (:members (r/reflect cls)))))
```

You can use it as follows:

```
=> (method-sig java.util.List "add")
;; returns 
({:name add,
  :return-type boolean,
  :declaring-class java.util.LinkedList,
  :parameter-types [java.lang.Object],
  :exception-types [],
  :flags #{:public}}
 {:name add,
  :return-type void,
  :declaring-class java.util.LinkedList,
  :parameter-types [int java.lang.Object],
  :exception-types [],
  :flags #{:public}})

 => (method-sig (java.util.LinkedList.) "add.*") ;; also works
```